# Django Piston: How can I exclude nested fields from handler results? Is it even possible?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-piston

I am putting the finishing touches on an API I have written for a Django app utilizing django-piston. The API is able to search by request or IP address which are `Request` or `IPAddress` instances respectively.  Each request can have 1 or more `IPAddress` associated with it.

So, for example I have an API call that will show all `IPAddress` objects matching an activity status of "active", "inactive", or "all" (for either).  The `Request` to which each `IPAddress` instance is associated is available as `IPAddress.request`.

The problem I am having is that `Request.inputter` is a foreign key to the `User` instance of the person who provisioned the request. When my results are returned from the handler I have created for this API call, all fields from the `User` instance are displayed, including `password`.

This is bad; I do not want this.

So here is my handler:

```
class SearchByIPStatusHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = IPAddress
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)
    anonymous = AnonymousIPHandler

    def read(self, request, status):
        """
        Returns IP addresses based on activity status.  
        Status: 'active', 'inactive', 'all'

        """
        if status == 'all':
            return self.model.objects.all()
        else:
            active = True if (status=='active') else False
            return self.model.objects.filter(active=active)
```

And here is an example of the results from `/api/show/all/`:

```
<response>
  <resource>
    <updated>2010-02-05 17:08:53.651729</updated>
    <expires>2010-02-12 17:08:23</expires>
    <created>2010-02-05 17:08:53.625318</created>
    <nexthop>255.255.255.255</nexthop>
    <netmask>255.255.255.254</netmask>
    <address>2.4.6.80/31</address>
    <active>True</active>
    <id>4</id>
    <request>
      <updated>2010-02-05 17:08:53.382381</updated>
      <created>2010-02-05 17:08:53.382313</created>
      <expires>2010-02-12 17:08:23</expires>
      <incident>20100212-badthings-01</incident>
      <reason>bad things happened</reason>
      <inputter>
        <username>jathan</username>
        <first_name>Jathan</first_name>
        <last_name>McCollum</last_name>
        <is_active>True</is_active>
        <email>email@fake.notreal</email>
        <is_superuser>True</is_superuser>
        <is_staff>True</is_staff>
        <last_login>2010-02-05 18:55:51.877746</last_login>
        <password>[ENCRYPTED STRING I REDACTED]</password>
        <id>1</id>
        <date_joined>2010-01-28 09:56:32</date_joined>
      </inputter>
      <requester>joeuser</requester>
      <active>True</active>
    </request>
  </resource>
</response>
```

All I really want in the results is the `inputter.username`, not all of the other stuff.  I have tried various iterations of implementing an `exclude` attribute on the handler to no avail.  If I just skip the entire request field, that works fine, like so:

In handler:

```
exclude = ('request', )
```

Which results in:

```
<response>
  <resource>
    <updated>2010-02-05 17:08:53.651729</updated>
    <expires>2010-02-12 17:08:23</expires>
    <created>2010-02-05 17:08:53.625318</created>
    <nexthop>255.255.255.255</nexthop>
    <netmask>255.255.255.254</netmask>
    <address>2.4.6.80/31</address>
    <active>True</active>
    <id>4</id>
  </resource>
</response>
```

But these results are also not what I want.

So, finally, my question:

**How can I exclude nested fields from handler results?  Is it even possible?**

I have tried various iterations of the following, all of which either have no result, or unintended results:

```
# try to exclude request.inputter
exclude = ( ('request', ('inputter', ), ) )

# try to exclude request.inputter.password
exclude = ( ('request', ('inputter', ('password', ) ) ) )
```

I assume that I am misunderstanding or misusing the way field exclusions are done in this context, so any enlightenment on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired result by specifying the desired fields via the handler's `fields =` clause.

Model fields coming from foreign keys can be specified like this:

```
('foreign_model_field', ('nested_field1', 'nested_field2'))
```

In your case, the following should work (some of your fields left out for brevity):

```
fields = ('updated', 'expires', 'created', 
    ('request', ('incident', 'reason', ('inputter', ('username',)))))
```

Comment: That does indeed work. Thanks for the response! More tedious than what I was hoping for (especially when I'll invetiably have to duplicate this across multiple handlers), but a solution is a solution!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using include instead of exclude? E.g.

```
include = (('request', ('inputter', ('username', 'therestofthefields'))))
```

I don't remember if I wrote `exclude` to be as versatile as `include`.

Also, the django-piston Google group is where we discuss most things, you may have more success asking this question there.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, Jesper.  I will dupe this on the mailing list.